# Using javascript functions into HTML page

Tags: javascript, html

I've already searched the Internet for an answer to my problem, but I did not found it.

When I try to use javascript functions (like: substring, lastIndexOf, etc.) inside a simple HTML page, I get an error.

As an example, see the following HTML page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
 <script type = "text/JavaScript" language="JavaScript">
  function redirect()
  {
   var URL = window.location;
   alert(URL.lastIndexOf("/"));
    
  }
 </script>
</head>
<body onload="javascript: redirect();">
</body>
```

The error is as follows:

[Javascript Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zchH.jpg)

How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance,

Marcelo Camarate

Comment: Please include code and output as content for your question, not as pictures or external links.

Comment: Why do you expect the `Location` object to have a function called `lastIndexOf()`?  What do you expect that function to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) has all these properties and methods ... and is not a string, so you cannot use those methods which are for strings.

[image: window.location]

So you need to use one of its properties, like href, which is an actual string.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
 <script type = "text/JavaScript" language="JavaScript">
  function redirect()
  {
   var URL = window.location.href;
   alert(URL.lastIndexOf("/"));
    
  }
 </script>
</head>
<body onload="javascript: redirect();">
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks Cody G. Working well with your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you're having this error is because window.location is an `Object` and `lastIndexOf` is a method of a string. 
Use window.location.href instead.

Answer (score 0):

lastIndexOf needs a string for it to work, make sure you reference the href property:

```js
function redirect() {
  var URL = window.location.href;
  alert(URL.lastIndexOf("/"));
}
```

```html
<body onload="redirect()">
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error message already explains what goes wrong: There is no function `lastIndexOf()` for your object `URL`. You expected a `string`, but `URL` is not a `string` (it is a `Location` object), therefore it does not have that function.

As explained above, use `window.location.href` instead, which actually is a `string`.

Answer (score 0):

New world huh ? Javascript language. Welcome mate. The error that is showing is because you are trying to use the function (lastIndexOf) in a type Object instead of a type string.

I think you are trying to do something like:

```
function redirect() {

        var URL = window.location.href; // LOOK AT THE HREF
        alert(URL.lastIndexOf("/"));

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`window.location` is an object so it has a bunch of properties (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) whereas you are using it like a string (`lastIndexOf` is a function belonging to string...). Probably you want:

```
var URL = window.location.href;
```

Be careful when you use the result though - the last "/" could be separating the protocol declaration ("http://", "https://" or later) depends what you are going to do with it.

Answer (score -1):

```
var URL = window.location.href;
```

Comment: Normally just a code snippet isn’t a good answer.

Comment: Thaks Amit and Richard. But my problem is not get the URL page. Is that the "lastIndexOf" javascript function is not recognized.

Answer (score -1):

Try `var URL = window.location.href;` instead of `var URL = window.location;`

Window.location returns a object and does not have lastIndexOf method, while window.location.href returns a string, which has method lasteIndexOf.

Comment: It might be good to explain why this works and the reasoning behind it.